# Include relative paths in .hgignore

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

How can I have  one `.hgignore` file include another `.hgignore` file by using a relative path?

The include methodology that I know (`include:<path-to-hgignore>`) requires `<path-to-hgignore>` to be rooted.

e.g., If I have the following files:

```
.hgignore
hgignore/all.hgignore
hgignore/eclipse.hgignore
hgignore/idea.hgignore
```

e.g., the following include in my root `.hgignore` works:

```
include:hgignore/all.hgignore
```

The only includes that I could get to work from inside `all.hgignore` had to be rooted, e.g.:

```
include:hgignore/eclipse.hgignore
include:hgignore/idea.hgignore
```

Trying to include any of the following paths from inside `all.hgignore` always results in `No such file or directory` errors:

```
include:eclipse.hgignore
include:./eclipse.hgignore
include:/eclipse.hgignore
```

Is there anything like the following that would work from inside `all.hgignore`?

```
include-relative:eclipse.hgignore
```